# Bring to front part of layout in android

Tags: android

I have a problem with parts of layout. I am adding buttons programmatically, because I want do something like breadcrump. I my solution work good. If I am in first activity I show one button. If I go to second I show two buttons. 
This is code:

```
public class TabsGenerator extends LinearLayout{



    public TabsGenerator(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public View addNewLinearLayout(Context context, ArrayList<String> descriptions) {
        final HorizontalScrollView horizontalView = new HorizontalScrollView(context);
        LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(context);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        params.height = 60;
        linearLayout.setLayoutParams(params);
        horizontalView.setLayoutParams(params);
        postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                horizontalView.fullScroll(HorizontalScrollView.FOCUS_RIGHT);
            }
        }, 100L);
        linearLayout.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
        List<View> components = getButtons(context, descriptions);
        for(View component : components) {
           linearLayout.addView(component);
        }
        horizontalView.addView(linearLayout);

        return horizontalView;
    }
    public List<View> getButtons(Context context, ArrayList<String> descriptions) {
        List<View> buttons = new ArrayList<View>();
        for(int i = 0; i < descriptions.size(); i++) {
           buttons.add(createButton(context,i, descriptions));
        }
        return buttons;
    }

    public View createButton(final Context context, final int i, final ArrayList<String> descriptions){

         LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
            params.leftMargin = -20;
        final Button button = new Button(context);
        button.setText(SecondActivity.descriptions.get(i));
        button.setBackgroundDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.paseknawigacji));
        button.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
        button.setEllipsize(TruncateAt.END);
        button.setSingleLine();
        button.setWidth(20);
        if(i==1)
            button.bringToFront();
        button.setLayoutParams(params);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.
                        getSystemService(Activity.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
                String packageName = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getPackageName();
                String className = am.getRunningTasks(1).get(0).topActivity.getClassName();
                final String StringClassname = packageName+"."+descriptions.get(i);
                Class<?> c = null;
                if(StringClassname != null) {
                    try {
                        c = Class.forName(StringClassname );
                    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setClassName(context,StringClassname);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                if(!(StringClassname.contains(className))){
                    for(int j = 0; j<descriptions.size()-1;j++)
                        if(i<descriptions.size()-1)
                            descriptions.remove(i+1);

                    context.startActivity(intent);

                }
            }
        });
        return button;
    }
}
```

I have a problem because buttons was added to layout but every buttons has ending by triangular shape. When I add second button he cover this shape.
This is how it is looks:
[image]
I want to bring to front ending every button. How I can do that?

Edit: Maybe is other way to create breadcrup in android?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add buttons in the reverse order

Your code

```
    List<View> components = getButtons(context, descriptions);
    for(View component : components) {
       linearLayout.addView(component);
    }
```

now in reverse order

```
    List<View> components = getButtons(context, descriptions);
    for(int i = components.size() - 1; i >= 0; i --) {
       View component = components.get (i);
       linearLayout.addView(component);
    }
```

(code not compiled, may have errors)

Comment: I check your solution but still the same result

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
thirdButton.bringtoFront();
SecondButton.bringToFront();
```

Your will see the triangular shape of third and second button.

Hope so this will work

Comment: As you can see in code I try bring to front button with index 1 but with no result

Comment: I think when you call createButton() function again... the recent button which is created comes up...

Answer (score 0):

I dont think yours will work with a linear layout as I have noticed that when using bring to front in a linear layout you automatically set it at the total end (eg its not longer button 1 button 2 button 3 but button 1 button 3 button 2). You would need to use a Relative layout or something similar. This might add a little logic to your code but it should be ok otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try setting elevation in your buttons
But I think the leftMargin= -20 is the reason why you cant see the ending triangle shape